# jQuery: adding event handler to just created element

Tags: jquery

I have a statement adding a new div:

```
$('#dates').append('<div class="'+classname+'">'+dd+'<br /><span class="month_selector">'+dm+'</span></div>');
```

But I'd like to not only create element but also to assign on('click') action to it.
Of course I could add generated id and then acces to created element by this id, but I feel that there is more beautiful solution.

Is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to add an id and then ask jQuery to parse a selector to find the element. You can directly do this :

```
$('#dates').append(
    $('<div class="'+classname+'">'+dd+'<br /><span class="month_selector">'+dm+'</span></div>')
    .click(function(){
      // handle click
    })
);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use jquery ON.. and also you can use class selector instead of id :) like `$(".classname")`

```
$('#dates').append('<div class="'+classname+'">'+dd+'<br /><span class="month_selector">'+dm+'</span></div>');

$('#dates').on('click','.'+classname, function(){
alert("on div click");
});

$('#dates').on('click','.month_selector', function(){
alert("on SPAN click");
});
```

Comment: If you use `.on()` you can do it once when the document is ready, you don't have to do it again when the element is added.