# Handle click event on a just created element

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have a jQuery statement adding new html code to an element, like this:

```
$(".welcome").removeClass("guest").addClass("user")
  .text("")
  .append("Welcome "+$('#username').val()+"! <a href=\"/admin/\" id=\"adminlink\">Control Panel</a> &mdash; ")
  .append(
    $("<a href=\"login.php?logout\" id=\"logoutlink\">Logout</a>").click(function(event)
        {
             $("#logoutlink").click();
        })
).fadeIn("slow");
```

I've used the append() method in order to allow jQuery to handle the click event on the  tag, but it's not working for some reason. 
I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729825/jquery-adding-event-handler-to-just-created-element), but I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: Your click handler just calls the click handler again.

Comment: Why not use event delegation as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Are you looking at something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7pdFF/

Comment: @Barmar I know that it calls the click handler again, I want it to do so because I have previously declared that handle.

Comment: @DavideR -- Then create a function that both handlers use, don't trigger a click event on a different element to do something, that could get ugly real quickl.

Comment: How could you have previously declared that handler? You're declaring it right there. You're creating an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind a click handler to an element that is appended to the DOM, you need to use event delegation, like this:

```
$(".welcome").removeClass("guest").addClass("user")
  .text("")
  .append("Welcome "+$('#username').val()+"! <a href=\"/admin/\" id=\"adminlink\">Control Panel</a> &mdash; ")
  .append(
    $("<a href=\"login.php?logout\" id=\"logoutlink\">Logout</a>"))
).fadeIn("slow");

$(document).on("click", "#logoutlink", function(){

    alert("do something");
});
```

For more information you can go [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/), and look at the section titled, "Direct and delegated events."

Comment: No problem, it is very easy to overlook!